# Short title issue

Tags: templates, apa7

I am new to using Latex and I am writing my first assigment using it to gain some experience. I've used a template to create my layout. But I am having two issues with it. For one, it prints this weird message at the top of my page which I cannot fix, and it also splits the refrences in both colomns without filling the left colomn first.

The template that I used is the following: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-and-sample-for-authoring-apa7-manuscripts/pvhtwcrvcmsp

My deadline is in a few hours, any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Screendump]

Comment: For question 1, in the preamble insert `\shorttitle{The Short Title of your Manuscript}`. If the title is already short, you can just use the same. For question 2: I am pretty sure that is by design.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You'll get faster answers here if you include a small compilable document that shows the problem you're having. In this case, since you probably don't need the short title, just add `\shorttitle{}` to your preamble. The `apa7` class is really designed to meet the requirements for submitting to APA journals or to producing documents that look like APA journal publications. It may not be the best choice for a homework assignment. You could try using the `[man]` option instead of the `[jou]` option.

Comment: For some explanation of the (mis)use of APA style, see [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793)